# Laravel 5 - Routes and variable parameters in controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I want to generate SEO friendly URLs like this when searching:
http://www.example.com/search (no filters)
http://**www.example.com/search/region-filter
http://**www.example.com/search/region-filter/city-filter

And to paginate them in this way:
http://www.example.com/search/2 (no filters, page 2)
http://**www.example.com/search/region-filter/2
http://**www.example.com/search/region-filter/city-filter/2

*(sorry I can't post more than 2 links because of reputation)*

So **the second segment can be a filter or a number of page** (and the same with the third one).

My Laravel 5 routing file:

```
Route::pattern('page', '[0-9]+');
...
Route::get('search/{region}/{city}/{page?}', 'SearchController@index');
Route::get('search/{region}/{page?}', 'SearchController@index');
Route::get('search/{page?}', 'SearchController@index');
```

Routes work fine because of the 'page' pattern, but inside the controller this petition http://**www.example.com/search/2 maps {page} in $region (even using last routing rule):

```
public function index($region='', $city='', $page='')
```

Codeigniter parameters are mapped by name, but it looks that Laravel maps them by position, so I always get the first one in $region.

**Is it possible to route parameters by name instead of position or use some Laravel alternative to get them in the controller?** (I can count segments, but it is an ugly solution for me)

Comment: Why don't you do something like this public function index($region = NULL, $city = NULL, $page = NULL) then, in your method if there's only search/{page} check if $page is a integer, if not, then it's your region. But $region will be your $page...I'd suggest you to separate your method for one routing. A lot easier.

Comment: I have thought something like you say (checking if it is a integer), but I was hoping Laravel would have some mechanism to do it cleaner. The other option you mean is to create three methods with one index and the other two 'pointing' to the index and passing parameters in the right order? I have done something similar in CI with the remap function, but again I expected Laravel would have something better.

Comment: I would create 3 different methods for your 3 routing. This way, you can be 100% sure that you will know exactly what kind of parameter you can play with in your method.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think I'll do that if there is no other option. I'm new to Laravel and I don't fully understand what the framework has and what are good practices.

Comment: The best way mate, is to check out their documentation. There's ton and ton of services, helpers you can help with. I am sorry to not be able to help you further on this. Good luck with Laravel!

Comment: Thank you again! Laravel it's being a breath of fresh air and even struggling with it is amazing. I'll continue checking out the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Route::current()` method to access the current route and get parameters by name via the [`parameter method`](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_parameter). However there is a problem with your route definitions, which would make the last two routes defined useless.

Because the `page` parameter in your last two routes is optional, depending on the route path your second and third routes will not match properly, because of the ambiguous definition of the routes. Below you have the test case which proves my point.

---

If you were to have this in your controller:

```php
public function index()
{
    $route = \Route::current();

    $region = $route->parameter('region');
    $city = $route->parameter('city');
    $page = $route->parameter('page');

    $params = [
        'region' => $region,
        'city' => $city,
        'page' => $page
    ];

    return $params;
}
```

You'll get the following results for each route:

**1.** For `example.com/search/myregion/mycity/mypage`:

```
{
    "region": "myregion",
    "city": "mycity",
    "page": "mypage"
}
```

**2.** For `example.com/search/myregion/mypage`:

```
{
    "region": "myregion",
    "city": "mypage",
    "page": null
}
```

**3.** For `example.com/search/mypage`:

```
{
    "region": "mypage",
    "city": null,
    "page": null
}
```

So your problem here is not with parameter matching by order or by name, it's with the route definitions. To fix this you can just have the pagination in the query string and drop it altogether the route definitions, because there's absolutely nothing wrong with having your pagination as a query string parameter if it's optional anyway. So your URL would look like this:

```
example.com/search/myregion/mycity?page=2
```

You can check the [Illuminate\Routing\Route](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html) class API to see what other methods you have available there.

Comment: This $route->getParameter() was exactly what I was searching for and I haven't seen it (I supposed Laravel had something like this, but I have searched in Request and Input instead of Route, but in Route had more sense).

About the routes matching, I just have noticed that and I was thinking about setting two routes (the first one with an integer required 'page' parameter and the second one without it, so it will match properly (although I would have to use twice rules)) or doing it as you have said with a query string. Anyway, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you.